# Error nested condition in dataframe.where ()

Tags: python, numpy

I have an error "where () takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given"
and I don't understand why, is your limited on the number of conditions, if yes how to do it, if not someone has an idea about my error
thanks in advance

```
temp["S1_fait"] = np.where(temp['Niveau_de_sensibilite'] == '1',
                    np.where(temp.Date_echeance_GSA2<=fin_annee_du_rapport,
                        np.where(temp.Date_echeance_GSA2<=septembre_annee_du_rapport,
                         np.where(temp.Date_echeance_GSA2<=mai_annee_du_rapport,
                          np.where(temp.Date_derniere_surveillance2>=debut_annee_du_rapport,
                                       temp['Longueur_installee']*1,
                                       0),
                          np.where(temp.Date_derniere_surveillance2>=mai_annee_du_rapport,
                                       temp['Longueur_installee']*2,
                                       temp['Longueur_installee']*1),
                                   np.where(temp.Date_derniere_surveillance2>septembre_annee_du_rapport,
                                    temp['Longueur_installee']*3,
                                    temp['Longueur_installee']*2)
                                   ),(temp['Longueur_installee']*3)),
                                0)
                           ,0)
```

Happy New Year's Eve

Comment: Use `np.select` instead?

Comment: It is not coded correctly for sure. simply use parenthesis for each parameter of np.where even though those are not necessary and you can solve it in seconds. I already see the 4th argument but cannot make out where to break your condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see why you're getting this error, see the documentation of `numpy.where` (which I would have assumed you would have read, considering you were using the function): https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

Its parameters are `condition[, x, y]`, meaning its first argument is `condition`, its second is `x` (which is optional), and `y`, which is also optional. Meaning, your fourth `np.where`, which has its first parameter as `temp.Date_echeance_GSA2<=mai_annee_du_rapport`, and then 3 more `np.where` statements, is what's throwing the error - because you're passing 4 parameters to `where` when it only ever expects 1 or 3.

It's not clear why you're doing that or what you're expecting to happen, or how you expect `numpy.where` to work, so I can't immediately recognize what your actual intentions are. So, I personally can't provide working code that does what you intended.